# R: pass variable from R to unix

Tags: r, variables, unix, send

I am running an R script via bash script and want to return the output of the R script to the bash script to keep working with it there.

The bash is sth like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
Rscript MYRScript.R
a=OUTPUT_FROM_MYRScript.R
do sth with a
```

and the R script is sth like this:

```
for(i in 1:5){
i
sink(type="message")
}
```

I want bash to work with one variable from R at the time, meaning: bash receives i=1 and works with that, when that task is done, receives i=2 and so on.

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: you want to construct a pipe from your running R-script to another shell-command. is it right?

Comment: Yes, but from R to unix, not unix to R

Comment: I want to use the R output (a filename) to be directly used in bash to modify another file there. Seems to me to be easier this way... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to make your R script executable with `#!/usr/bin/env Rscript` (setting the executable bit; e.g. `chmod 0755 myrscript.r`, `chmod +x myrscript.r`, etc...), and just treat it like any other command, e.g. assigning the results to an array variable below:

**myrscript.r**

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
cat(1:5, sep = "\n")
```

**mybashscript.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
RES=($(./myrscript.r))
for elem in "${RES[@]}"
do
  echo elem is "${elem}"
done
```

---

```
nrussell$ ./mybashscript.sh
elem is 1
elem is 2
elem is 3
elem is 4
elem is 5
```

Comment: strangely enough I get a Permission denied (for myrscript.r) error when running your solution. Any ideas why?

Comment: Do a `chmod 0755 myrscript.r` first,

Comment: @gugy Sorry I kind of glossed over that in my answer; thank you Dirk.

Comment: How to prevent printing of R startup intro in output?

Answer (score 0):

Here is **MYRScript.R**:

```
for(iter in 1:5) {
  cat(iter, ' ')
}
```

and here is your `bash` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

r_output=`Rscript ~/MYRscript.R`

for iter in `echo $r_output`
do
    echo Here is some output from R: $iter
done
```

---

```
Here is some output from R: 1
Here is some output from R: 2
Here is some output from R: 3
Here is some output from R: 4
Here is some output from R: 5
```